# MYSQL- Create and store primary key in master and child table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, database

```
I got stuck while insertion into database tables.
I have below tables.
```

[image: Table Relations]

I dont have any fields which can be make as Primary key.

**Here "eme_request" and "eme_attachment" is master tables.**

I want to know that how can I insert into tables ? 
These tables(eme_request, eme_gf_relevent, eme_non_gf_relevent, eme_attachment) are getting insertion on one form request.

So I am not getting how to generate primary key in master table and how to insert into child table with that primary key as a Foreign key ?

Answer (score 1):

In `eme_request` table `REQ_ID` (your `PK`) is type of `varchar`. If you can change it to `INT` and add flag `AUTOINCREMENT`, you will get automatically generated key.

If you can't change type of `REQ_ID` (you need it to be char), just add abstract `PRIMARY_KEY` `int` column and use it.

After inserting into table with autoincrement column you can receive assigned key with
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id so it can be used as FOREIGN KEY for other tables.

Comment: I used it logically.. It cannot lead to the solution.

Comment: Ok. I don't understand your question then.